# AKRhodesPiano error (crush) on AudioKit v4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

I'm using [AudioKit version 4.2](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases/tag/v4.2) and I receive this error (see attached image) after installing my app on my phone (iPhone X) - [Xcode error when using AKRhodesPiano](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiJ8b.jpg)

The error is thrown after the app is compiled and installed (after the app is being opened on the device).

This is the line that I'm using:

```
let pianoNote = AKRhodesPiano() // error
```

When I change this line to a different instrument, for example -

```
let pianoNote = AKPluckedString() // works good!
```

Can someone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved on 4.2.2 and later.

Tested and verified.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/AudioKit

Answer (score 2):

Some of the STK Physical models got screwed up on a recent release.  We're hoping to have it resolved in AudioKit 4.2.1.  Really sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you know when is AudioKit 4.2.1 due?