# AKTubularBells() and AKRhodesPiano() together cause error on the second

Tags: audiokit

I'm using AKRhodesPiano() and AkTubularBells(). Both work alone. When I try to initialize both, I get the following error.

```
AKRhodesPiano.swift:init(frequency:amplitude:):88:Parameter Tree Failed
```

Notably, if I change the order of initialization, the error occurs for the last one of the two instantiated.

Adding the following line to the AKTubularBells playground right under the initialization of AKTubularBells  is enough to trigger the error.

```
let tubularBells = AKTubularBells()
let temp = AKRhodesPiano()  /// <- Add this line.
```

I saw in another post [AKRhodesPiano error (crush) on AudioKit v4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618665/akrhodespiano-error-crush-on-audiokit-v4-2) that there was a recent error in the STK Physical models, so perhaps this is part of that. Any insight appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for noticing this, it only occurred when using those two nodes simultaneously, but it was basically just a cut-and-paste job gone bad. I fixed it on develop, so if you can rebuild the framework you'll be fine or else wait for the next release which should be soon.

Here's the fix:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/05651ff97a7ea7815a27de6a53eee0b5f7998920

Comment: The perfect answer. Thanks for all your work on this.